# Terraform error - Extra characters after interpolation expression

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-template-file

I'm trying to pass a terraform variable to templatefile like the following:

```
templatefile("${path.module}/functions/nodejs/node_modules/up.js", {
    canary_url = var.canary_url
  })
```

where the up.js file looks like:

```
const urls = ['http://${canary_url}'];
```

I want to pass the value of canary_url variable which is a url looks like "xxxxx.com", I don't want to escape it, so **$${canary_url}** is not what I'm looking for. however, when I try to use **$${canary_url}** or **${canary_url}** I get the same error:

```
Call to function "templatefile" failed: ../../modules/cloudwatch/functions/nodejs/node_modules/up.js:81,87-88: Extra characters after interpolation
│ expression; Expected a closing brace to end the interpolation expression, but found extra characters.
│
│ This can happen when you include interpolation syntax for another language, such as shell scripting, but forget to escape the interpolation start token. If
│ this is an embedded sequence for another language, escape it by starting with "$${" instead of just "${"..
```

Comment: I tested this with `Terraform v1.5.0` and it works fine.

Comment: @Paolo I just upgraded my Terraform from v1.3 to v1.5 and tried it and I still get the same error. what exactly did you tried? $ ? $$?

Comment: I tried exactly what you show in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine:

```bash
$ cat up.js
const urls = ['http://${canary_url}'];

$ terraform console
> templatefile("${path.module}/up.js", { canary_url = "foo" })
<<EOT
const urls = ['http://foo'];

EOT
```